# cannot GET/ chat socket.io

Tags: html, node.js, socket.io

Estou tentando iniciar o serviço do socket.io, mas aparece o erro
Cannot GET/

meu server.js está assim

```
var socket  = require( './node_modules/socket.io' );
var express = require('./node_modules/express');
var app     = express();
var server  = require('http').createServer(app);
var io      = socket.listen( server );
var port    = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var users = [];

server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server listening on port %d', port);
});
```

Quando executo node server.js
ele inicia o serviço, mas qual tento acessar a url aparace Cannot GET/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que está a faltar qual o serviço (URL) em que vai executar determinada função, e quando acede envie o ficheiro que pretende ver no browser:

Ou seja:

```
...
var users = [];

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/chat.html'); // colocar isto de acordo a sua estrutura de diretorios
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', 'isto veio do server: ' +msg);
  });
});

server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server listening on port %d', port);
});
```

chat.html:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.6/socket.io.js">

</script>
<script>

var socket = io();

socket.emit('chat message', 'olá');

socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    alert(msg);
});

</script>
```

E agora aceda ao url `...:3000/`

Comment: Funcionou, mas agora não consigo acessar a aplicação... só quando coloco ele no servidor, acessando localhost/chat, ai executa, porem não fica em tempo real...

Comment: Como assim? Você tem uma página por ex: index.html que quer ver no browser?

Comment: Vou editar consoante o que creio que seja preciso

Comment: Isso, tenho um chat, ta funcionando já, mas só quando acesso ele pelo Wamp, e quando tentava acessar pelo localhost:3000 dava cannot get, agora não aparece mas o erro, mas a pagina fica em branco.

Comment: dê-me uns mins.

Comment: Editei em cima, veja se resolve